# JAR file does not play sound while Eclipse does

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I have a project that I want to export as a jar file. The software is supposed to play a sound at a certain point in time. However, the problem is that the JAR file does not play the sound file when that point in time is reached. When I run the same project from the Eclipse IDE, it does.

Here is the code that shows how I setup the sound playback capabilities:

```
public void setupSoundPlayback(){
        try{
            buzzer = AudioSystem.getClip();

            in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(BatteryBeeper.class.
                    getResourceAsStream("/sound/boing_x.wav"));

            buzzer.open(in);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Later, I call the `play()` method of `Clip` object.
Although I am using the `getResourceAsStream()` method to play embedded sound, the JAR does not play the sound.

---

[image]

As I was told to extract and see if the sound file was at its proper place, I did. Here is what I got. The sound folder is in the root. And the `boing3_x.wav` is in the sound folder (not in the picture).

Comment: Are you sure your jar is able to find the file correctly? Eclipse does some odd things with paths sometimes.

Comment: @JesusRamos How do I know if JAR can find it properly ?

Comment: Run the jar from the command line and see if you get a stack trace.

Comment: Where is this jar running from? maybe you got security restricions (eg: webstart)?

Comment: @fscan It is running from a folder in the `E:\` drive.

Comment: to list the contents of the jar you can type "jar -tf file" or open it in winrar or similar program. Also check if BatteryBeeper is in the same jar.

Comment: @fscan Please have a look at the edits.

Comment: Try running the jar from the command line like JesusRamos said (java -jar jarfile) and see if it throws any exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the call `getResourceAsStream("/sound/boing_x.wav");`, you should make sure that the .wav file is enclosed in the JAR in the correct location.

Since you have a '/' at the beginning of the path, the .wav file will need to be located *inside the JAR* in the path you specified, using absolute pathing (i.e. sound directory needs to be located in the root of the JAR, and boing_x.wav needs to be located in the sound directory).

I would recommend unzipping your JAR file to a particular directory and making sure that when you unzip the JAR, you see `/sound/boing_x.wav`.

Comment: @LittleChild I know this isn't a clean solution, but just to troubleshoot, try copying the boing_x.wav file into the same directory as the `BatteryBeeper` class, change your call to `getResourceAsStream("boing_x.wav");` re-jar, and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the resource, in your case the .wav file, is not embedded inside the built .jar file or is embedded at a wrong location.

Also please note that you are trying to play "/sound/**boing_x.wav**", but you also mention that in the jar, in /sound you have **boing***3***_x.wav**, so the file name has an extra ***3*** in its name.

Comment: There are two `boing` files. :) one playes 3x and the other only once

Comment: `"E:\Eclipse Projects\BatteryBeeper\src\sound\buzzer3_x.wav"`
`"E:\Eclipse Projects\BatteryBeeper\src\sound\boing_x.wav"`
`"E:\Eclipse Projects\BatteryBeeper\src\sound\bubbling1.wav"`

Answer (score 1):

This is my function for playing a looping sound file in jars, it works fine for me.

It appears that `getResourceAsStream()` doesn't work with jars. however, `getResource()` does.

```
public synchronized void alarm() {
    try {
        crit = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("critical.wav"));
        crit.open(inputStream1);
        crit.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```